# When are the local remote-tracking branches created in Git?

Tags: git

In the local Git repository this folder contains the HEAD file just after a clone:

```
.git\refs\remotes\origin\
```

When I create a local branch from a remote-tracking branch that branch will be created in:

```
.git\refs\heads
```

When I push changes on that local branch to the remote repository a new copy of that branch is created in:

```
.git\refs\remotes\origin\
```

So are remote-tracking branches first created in the above folder when they are initially pushed to the remote repository?

Comment: *So are remote-tracking branches first created in the above folder when they are initially pushed to the remote repository?* Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not care *where* branches are stored (as you should use the "advertised" interfaces, `git branch`, `git for-each-ref`, and so on).  The *when* question is more interesting though.

A remote-tracking branch is simply a reference in the `refs/remotes` name-space.  Normally there's one more level added to this, specifically the name of the remote itself, so that for the remote named `origin`, the branches will all fall into `refs/remotes/origin`.

The `git clone` command creates a `remote` configuration entry in your local git configuration file (for that repository).  This configuration entry will, assuming you tell `git clone` to use the default `origin` name, read in part:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is where the name-space comes from: the `fetch` line(s) in the `remote.origin` configuration entry, i.e., the stuff from:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

The actual remote-tracking branch *creation* occurs in several places.

The most obvious is when `fetch` (or the initial `clone` step, which includes a slight variation on `fetch`) or `git remote update` runs.  These commands ask the remote about its references.  Those that match one or more `fetch` lines are copied over and *modified* based on the right-hand side of each refspec.

This means that, during `git clone`, `git fetch origin`, or `git remote origin update`, if the remote has a `refs/heads/foo` (branch `foo`), your own local repository acquires a corresponding `refs/remotes/origin/foo`.  If you did not have one before, this creates a (local) remote-tracking branch.

(If you run `git fetch` such that you prevent it from fetching branch `foo`, though, the tracking-branch does *not* get created.  For instance if you run `git fetch origin refs/heads/bar:refs/temp_bar`, this fetch brings over only `refs/heads/bar`.  Different versions of git will or will not create or update `refs/remotes/origin/bar` at this time: pre-1.8.4 won't, but newer gits will.  All this assumes the normal `fetch` configuration.)

A less-obvious case occurs during `git push`.  In this case, when your local git successfully delivers a reference to the remote's `refs/heads` name-space, your local git will also create or update a remote-tracking branch using the same refspec mapping as `git fetch`.  **Hence, with the default settings, pushing `refs/heads/new` such that it *creates* branch `foo` on remote `origin` *also* creates a (local) remote-tracking branch `refs/remotes/origin/new`.**  (I put this in bold because I *think* it's the answer to the question I *think* you're asking.)

If you add `--prune` to a `git fetch` or `git remote update` command, it will also *remove* remote-tracking branches at that time, if they are now missing on the remote—they can tell because they get *all* references from the remote.  (Keep in mind that this is very different from `git push`'s `--prune` option, which is meant for deleting branches on the remote, a la `git push --delete` or `git push :dst`.)